# How to disable SSL certificate check for a single websocket-connection?

Tags: powershell, websocket, ssl-certificate

I am loocking for an option to disable the SSL cert validation for a single websocket connection. My server in question uses a self-signed certificate only.
This is the Powershell code that I have so far:

```
$server  = 'server1'
$cred    = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials to access '$server'"

# setting credentials for any required proxy-authentication:
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

# define settings for http-client:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
$handler = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::new()
$ignoreCerts = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
$handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = $ignoreCerts
$handler.Credentials = $cred
$handler.PreAuthenticate = $true
$client  = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new($handler)

# generate websocket-key:
$init  = [guid]::NewGuid().Guid.Substring(0,16)
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($init)
$key   = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

# request protocol switch:
$url  = [string]::Concat('https://', $server)
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Connection', 'Upgrade,Keep-Alive')
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Upgrade', 'WebSocket')
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13')
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Sec-WebSocket-Key', $key)
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('Origin', "wss://$server")
$response = $client.GetAsync($url).result
if ($response.StatusCode -eq 'BadGateway'){break}
```

Here I need a better solution than this "big bang" approach. In best case I am able to disable the cert validation only for this single websocket client/connection like I could do it for the above http-handler:

```
# skip SSL-Validation for websocket communication:
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

If cert-validation is disabled, then we can do a quick connection-test to the server:

```
$ws  = [System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket]::new()
$ct  = [System.Threading.CancellationToken]::new($false)
$url = [string]::Concat('wss://', $server)

# connect to server:
$conn = $ws.ConnectAsync($url, $ct)
$null = [Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAll($conn)

# check websocket-status:
$ws | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current solution? Which properties would make an alternative solution "better" in your opinion?

Comment: As mentioned, my goal is disabling SSL cert validation for the websocket-object only like for the HTTP Handler object. MSDN mentions a ClientWebSocketOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback for this but I cannot see how to use it in Powershell.